# How to upload a file in Symfony 1.2 without using a specific form

Tags: file-upload, symfony1, save, filesystems, action

I haven't done much file uploading in Symfony to this point and I'm trying to figure out how to do it in 1.2+

I can get the files submitted to the action and retrieve them via:

```
$files = $request->getFiles();
```

How can I get then save the file to the file system?  I don't see any documentation besides the old 1.0 depreciated code.

It looks like this has been moved somehow into the form system but I don't have a specific for for this one-off page that I have that does nothing but upload a few files.

How can I save these files to disc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not looking to upload the files using the symfony forms then the following coded will also work:

```
foreach($request->getFiles() as $file)
{
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $directory . "/" . $file['name']);
}
```

Comment: of course, that's the "regular" php way to do it, it will work regardless of the framework used

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is what I was looking for if I don't have a form class to use.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the action, after you bind the params to the form:

```
  $file = $your_form->getValue('your_file_field');

  $filename  = $file->getOriginalName(); //or whatever name
  $extension = $file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
  $file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$filename.$extension);
```

btw, you can find the documentation for Symfony 1.2 in the corresponding Symfony Forms in Action book: [Chapter 02 file upload](http://symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/02-Form-Validation#chapter_02_file_upload)

ps : Don't forget to manually add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your html form!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation

Comment: Check that link, it seems to be broken

Comment: fixed link, there seems to be a problem with the symfony page and external links (it doesn't like the 'www' part in the url...)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you friend.
I'm looking for this code for 2 days. I'm new to php even i'm trying symfony. 
My code for symfony.

```
$this->filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
foreach ( $request -> getFiles () as  $file )
{ 
    if(move_uploaded_file ( $file [ "tmp_name" ],  sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/myfile/'.  $file [ 'name' ]))
    { 
        $this-setTemplate('success');
    } 
    else
    {
        $this-setTemplate('failure')
    }
}
```

same way use the `$filetype` to check the uploaded file type. Check php file reference. For file types. Enjoy..

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking why you can't access to the uploaded file using $request->getFiles(), it might be because you forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Actually, you should have a form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/yourdestination" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="somedummyfile"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

And your action should do something like this:

```
$dummyfile = $request->getFiles('somedummyfile');
echo $dummyfile['tmp_name']; // Current filepath
echo $dummyfile['name']; // filename
```

Hope it helps !